# How to call HttpException in setTimeout, when i wait promise a long time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, exception, nestjs

I get products from different servers, I want return exception, when wait a long time.
I have created setTimeout for this, but it stoped server and didn't return error.

How to fix it?

```
      const server = 23;

      const productsTimeout = setTimeout(() => { throw new HttpException('Problem', HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR) }, 3000);

      products = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.socketClientCabinet.on('products_get', async ({ server, products }) => {
          if (server === serverID) {
            const {
              productsSymbols,
            } = this.productsTransform(products);

            clearTimeout(productsTimeout);

            resolve(productsSymbols);
          }
        });
      });
```

Comment: Why trigger an exception? I would `reject(new Error("<meaningful message"))` the `Promise()` after `x` seconds: `new Promise((resolve, reject) => { setTimeout(() => reject(new Error("Ups")), 5000);  /*...*/ }`

Comment: @Andreas Slight syntax improvement: `setTimeout(reject, 5000, new Error('Ups'))`.

Comment: @Andreas The socket server may return the desired data in the next response, but I need to fix the timeout for this response.

Comment: Maintain `isTimedOut` and set it inside `setTimeout` . Pass it to other operations that need to reject once this is set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User delete his answer, I have fixed it.

```
      let productsTimeout;

      const timeoutPromise = new Promise((res, rej) => {
        instrumentsTimeout = setTimeout(() => rej(new HttpException('problem', 500)), 1000, )
      })

      const productsPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.socketClientCabinet.on('products_get', async ({ server, products }) => {
          if (server === serverID) {
            const {
              productsSymbols,
            } = this.productsTransform(products);

            clearTimeout(productsTimeout);

            resolve(productsSymbols);
          }
        });
      });

      const products = await Promise.race([
        timeoutPromise,
        productsPromise
      ])
```

It is work.

Comment: Nice ... !!! using Promises...

Comment: Yes, it came to me late it is **race** not **any** the one you need.